# Attaching touch event listeners to a video element in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I've got a container div with a video element inside it. The container has touch event handlers but in Firefox instead of the touch events being handled by the container, it plays/pauses the video and doesn't propagate. I've also tried adding event listeners to the video itself, but it behaves the same way (plays/pauses the video).

I'd like the touch events to be handled by my own functions, as they are in other browsers. Is this possible?

Here is an example which uses jQuery, but it behaves the same way without jQuery:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('vid-container');
var vid = document.getElementById('vid');

$(container).bind('touchstart', function() {
  alert('Container touchstart');
});

$(vid).bind('touchstart', function() {
  alert('Vid touchstart');
});
```

```css
#vid-container {
  background: blue;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

#vid {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vid-container">
  <video id="vid" controls>
    <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8h1z7Lxm/5/